# If $p$ is a prime number and $G$ is non-abelian group of order $p^3$, $G/Z(G) \cong Z_p \times Z_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is kinds of extension of [Let G be a nonabelian group of order $p^3$, where $p$ is a prime number. Prove that the center of $G$ is of order $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443710/let-g-be-a-nonabelian-group-of-order-p3-where-p-is-a-prime-number-prove-t)

What i want to do is following

If $p$ is a prime number and $G$ is non-abelian group of order $p^3$, 
$G/Z(G) \cong Z_p \times Z_p$.

What i know is that 
$|Z(G)|=p$, and conclude the isomorphism to product of $Z_p$.

How to prove this?

Comment: Imho this is not an extension but simply a duplicate.

Comment: I know $|G/Z(G)|=p^2$, but how this shows that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the center has order $p$, then $G/Z(G)$ has order $p^2$, so according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415825/group-g-of-order-p2-g-cong-mathbb-z-p2-or-g-cong-mathbb-z-p-tim?rq=1), it must be equal to either $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z $ or $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Since it can't be cyclic has otherwise $G$ would be abelian, $G/Z(G)$ must be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem~4.3.8 implies a non-trivial center which must have order $p$, else the group is either trivially abelian $\left|Z\left(P\right)\right|=p^{3}$ or, by Exercise~3.1.36, $\left|Z\left(P\right)\right|=p^{2}$ implies the group is abelian. On the other hand, $\left|Z\left(P\right)\right|=p$ and $P/Z\left(P\right)\cong Z_{p^{2}}$ also imply, via Exercise~3.1.36, that the group is abelian. There is only one possibility, $P/Z\left(P\right)\cong Z_{p}\times Z_{p}$.

Altenatively, $P$ is a non-abelian group of order $p^{3}$ so there are the standard constructions
\begin{align*}
    \left\langle y\right\rangle\rtimes\left\langle x\right\rangle
    &=\left\langle\left. x,y\right|\ x^{p}=y^{p^{2}}=1,\ xyx^{-1}=y^{p+1}\right\rangle\\
    \left(\left\langle a\right\rangle\times\left\langle b\right\rangle\right)\rtimes\left\langle x\right\rangle
    &=\left\langle\left. x,a,b\right|\ x^{p}=a^{p}=b^{p}=1,\ ab=ba,\ xax^{-1}=ab,\ xbx^{-1}=b\right\rangle
\end{align*}
and Theorem~6.1.1(2) implies $\left\langle y\right\rangle\cap Z\left(P\right)=\left\langle y^{p}\right\rangle\cong Z_{p}$ and $\left(\left\langle a\right\rangle\times\left\langle b\right\rangle\right)\cap Z\left(P\right)=\left\langle b\right\rangle\cong Z_{p}$, respectively. Then there are the homomorphisms
\begin{align*}
    \phi_{1}:\left\langle y\right\rangle\rtimes\left\langle x\right\rangle
    &\rightarrow\left\langle y\right\rangle\rtimes\left\langle x\right\rangle /\left\langle y^{p}\right\rangle\cong\left\langle y^{p}\right\rangle\times\left\langle x\right\rangle\\
    \phi_{2}:\left(\left\langle a\right\rangle\times\left\langle b\right\rangle\right)\rtimes\left\langle x\right\rangle
    &\rightarrow\left(\left\langle a\right\rangle\times\left\langle b\right\rangle\right)\rtimes\left\langle x\right\rangle /\left\langle b\right\rangle\cong\left\langle a\right\rangle\times\left\langle x\right\rangle
\end{align*}
In either case, $P/Z\left(P\right)\cong Z_{p}\times Z_{p}$.

Comment: Can you state which textbook you follow?

Comment: Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra, 3rd ed.