# There are exactly two abelian groups of order $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number.  up to isomorphism, there is exactly two abelian groups of order $p^2$.

It is easy to see those two are $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. It is easy to see that *if* their exist another one then it should not be cyclic. But how to prove **exactly**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There exists only two groups of order $p^2$ up to isomorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317356/there-exists-only-two-groups-of-order-p2-up-to-isomorphism).

Comment: how I could not find this one when I search!!! Strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider 2 cases: whether or not there exists an element of order $p^2$. If it does exist, then the group is $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$. If not, then you have to prove that this condition forces the group to be $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$

To prove that consider two elements $x \in G, y \in G\backslash\langle x \rangle$ of order $p$ and the group generated by them:

$| \langle x, y \rangle | > | \langle x \rangle |$, hence $G = \langle x, y \rangle.$ It is easy to see from here that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$

Comment: So every non-cyclic groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$, that's all, isn't?

Comment: @MANMAID Yes, it is

Answer (score 0):

See here 
[fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification).

Comment: This is way overkill.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317356/there-exists-only-two-groups-of-order-p2-up-to-isomorphism), which is not using an "overkill".